# How can I reset the route in Google Maps from my Android App

Tags: android, google-maps

When a user of my Android Google Maps API V2 app selects a marker on the map I set a latlng called MOCK_LOCATION to the location of the marker.  When the user then clicks a certain button I show the route in Google Maps where the user can choose to follow the navigation if they wish to.

This all works wonderfully well...THE FIRST TIME.  When the user switches back to my app and chooses a different marker and then clicks the button again, the Google Maps app is displayed with the first route.  I have found if I manually remove the route in the Maps app, then the button works again.

The obvious aim of this question is therefore: How can I clear the route before loading the app with the new destination/route again?

All help much appreciated.

See code below:

```
public void clickDrive(View view) {
    if (MOCK_LOCATION == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select a destination site first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+MOCK_LOCATION.latitude+","+MOCK_LOCATION.longitude+" (" + MOCK_SITE + ")&dirflg=d";  //d=driving, r=transport w=walking
    Intent driveRoute = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

    Log.i(LogTAG, uri);
    if (isAppInstalled("com.google.android.apps.maps")) {
        driveRoute.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    }
    startActivity(driveRoute);
}
```

Comment: Mmmm - very interesting development.  I found that I did not have the same problem on a another device (both devices I tested were Galaxy S3 phones).  Turns out the one that was not working correctly (for my purposes) had a Developer Option called "Do not keep activities" enabled.  Once this was disabled both devices handled the activity in the maps app as I would have expected.

Comment: The "Do not keep activities" option, if enabled, will destroy activities when the user navigates away from them.  When testing multiple-activity apps, the options is rather dangerous to have enabled.